# Rails: Migration for new has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-migrations

I'm very new to Ruby and to Rails, So this is some kind of "Tell me what I'm doing wrong" question:

I've got a project with some existing `ApplicationRecords`. Now I like to add a new `has_many` association to one of them (called "Task").

```
has_many :assistants, class_name: "User"
```

I am providing the class name here as there is already another existing association `has_many :users`. (There can be 0-* assistants for every task.)

What is the right way to create the `Migration` for this? I've created the following:

```
class AddAssistantsToTask < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    add_reference :tasks, :assistant, null: true, foreign_key: {to_table: :users}, type: :uuid
  end
end
```

In the controller, I try to add Users to the assistant association:

```
if !@task.assistants.includes(@user)
    @task.assistants << @user
end
```

To this point it seems like everything is running as expected. When I try to query the added User using the Rails Console using

```
Task.find("some id").assistants.count
```

I get error messages, that the column `users.task_id` doesn't exist.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Should this be a has_many :through (or has_and_belongs_to_many if you feel lucky)  association? I assume a single user can be an assistant to multiple tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the statement in the wrong direction

you have a `task` that `has_many` `assistants`, so the `foreign_key` should be on the `assistant` model, in this case Users

```rb
class AddAssistantsToTask < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    # Add foreign key assistant_id to users that points to tasks
    add_reference :users, :assistant, type: :uuid, null: true, foreign_key: { to_table: :tasks }
  end
end
```

Now you can see that the name assistant_id on table Users doesn't make sense, so I would rename to something like assisted_task or just task

```rb
class AddAssistantsToTask < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    # Add foreign key assistant_id to users that points to
    add_reference :users, :assisted_task, type: :uuid, null: true, foreign_key: { to_table: :tasks }
  end
end
```

```rb
has_many :assistants, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :assisted_task_id
```

or with `task`

```rb
class AddAssistantsToTask < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    # Add foreign key assistant_id to users that points to
    add_reference :users, :task, type: :uuid, null: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

```rb
has_many :assistants, class_name: "User"
```

But I do agree with @BroiSatse, that this should be an many-to-many relation, because you are limiting each user to just have one task